# jquery passing draggable object from dropped div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

i want to change the background of the draggable object after being dropped in the droppable division. how can i pass the current object being dropped?

assume there is #drag div and #drop div. after moving #drag into #drop div. I want to change the color of #drag div to black.

```
$("#drop").droppable({
    drop: function(){
        $(this).css('background','black');
    },
});
```

i have no idea how to pass the dragged element into the droppable object after dragging and dropping it into the #drop div. I assumed 'this' would work. but it seems that it points to the #drop div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
...
drop: function(event, ui) {

  // here ui.draggable is the object that was dragged 
  ui.draggable.css('background','black');


}
...
```